create np array with [] column items
I created a NumPy array where the elements are all empty arrays. I expected the shape to be (2,), but it returned (2, 0).
d = np.array([[],[]],dtype=object)
print(d,d.shape)

output:
[] (2, 0)


how to create np array with []

Maybe explain the use case since what you're trying to do is unusual.

(2,0) is a 2d array, with 2 'rows' and 0 'columns'.  The rows have 0 elements. roughly the equivalent of a empty list.  (2,) is a 1d array with 2 elements - what those elements are depends on the dtype.  np.empty(2, object) makes a (2,) with None elements.

thank you, I use np.empty solve this problem
